# Lettuce-Core-6.2.x Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/resolver/AddressResolverGroup

Tags: redis, lettuce

While migrating from biz.paluch.redis.lettuce-4.4.6.Final to io.lettuce.lettuce-core-6.2.x, I am seeing the below exception -

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBZZ7.png)

Here's the dependency I am using -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anyone please help ?

Tried excluding io.netty dependencies and added them separately.